# Adding Credit Cards to Paypal account

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

My scenario is something like this:

There are n number of users of my app and each of them have their own credit cards and paypal accounts. Those credit cards are not yet linked to their paypal account. Is there a way they can link it with their account from my app using SDK or REST API calls.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

No. it wouldn't be in your interest as well as you would need to be PCI compliant to handle credit card data. it's much better to leave it to the PYPL experience to guide the users to add their credit cards